# Represent time window of sensor data

Tags: classification

I have labeled time windows of data from different sensors(gyroscope, accelerator, magnetometer). For all sensor data, the format is:

```
(x,y,z,timestamp)
```

For a classification purpose, how do I represent the sensor data? 
How exactly do I make meaningful feature extractions of the raw sensor data so it can be used for classification?
Does a mean of a given time window makes sense?

The purpose and goal is to classify activities from these time windows of sensor data.

Comment: Just randomly classifying data doesn't help anything. Generally, you'll need some context with that data, after all the accelerator data is going to look very different when sitting still versus doing loops in the air.  Without the context, how do you know the "loops in the air" data isn't normal for sitting still? Also, what are you trying to determine from the data? Answer that and it will go a long ways to allow you to figure out what data is meaningful and should be grouped togeither so it can be used for classification.

Comment: Using the mean makes sense for some sensors and not for others. Sometimes you'll need to use the median if there's occasional outlier glitches in the readings as those outliers will play havoc on the mean. Other sensors may need something entirely different, like a best fit curve/predictor. Many older radar systems need this because the data tends to be spotty and noisy.  The only way to know what makes sense is to collect data and see what best models your needs.